# Swift loses leading zero

Tags: ios, swift, time, int

I'm trying to pass an int to another class like `0902` and the sent result loses the first zero. This only happens when a zero is leading.

I also have a function which tries to add it in but that doesn't work either. Is there a reason in Swift for not keeping a leading zero Int?

If I send a value of `0902` to another class what gets shown afterwards is `902`, totally confused.

```
    func convertToTime(_ value: Int) -> String {
      print(value) // 902 
      var text = String(format: "%02d", value)
      text.insert(":", at: text.index(text.startIndex, offsetBy: +2))
      return text
    }
```

Comment: why should it keep 0, it means nothing for Int in this form

Comment: Leading zeroes are of no value and since it's an int, which is a numeric digit, it will lose the leading zero. If you intend to have a leading zero, try converting it to string instead.

Comment: @Lu_ is right. 0 means nothing for Int. You can declare it as string rather than integer if you wish to do so.

Comment: Are you asking about `convertToTime` method or another thing? Basically `int` is converting your 0902 to 902 if you're passing value with `int` data type

Comment: do let us know what you are trying to achieve using above method. i hope we can help.From where are you getting '0902' value ??

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is how you define the type of that value "0902"?

Is it **really** a number?

Or is it actually a String that only contains numeric values?

Like a telephone number for instance. Is that a number? Or a string?

Would you want to add them together? Or multiply them? If not, make it a String.

Once you make it a string, the leading 0 is no longer an issue as it is just part of the string. As soon as you make it into a number then it makes no sense for the leading zero to be there as `0902 == 902`.

**Additional**

Having had another look at this... Is it even a string? You are dealing with time here? So surely you should be using an NSDate object?

The problem is still the same though. Make sure you define your types correctly.

Determine what this "0902" actually is. Then make it the correct type for that.

Whether that be a number, a string, or a date.

The correct type will then ensure that you get the correct formats, and functions and properties of it.

Answer (score 0):

Change your function argument to String:

```
func convertToTime(_ value: String) -> String {
    print(value) // prints "0902"
    var text = value
    text.insert(":", at: text.index(text.startIndex, offsetBy: +2))
    return text
}

convertToTime("0902") // prints "09:02"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
func convert(integerToTimeString int: Int) -> String{
    var string = "\(int)"
    if string.count > 3{
        string.insert(":", at: string.index(string.startIndex, offsetBy: String.IndexDistance(2)))
        return string
    }
    string.insert("0", at: string.startIndex)
    string.insert(":", at: string.index(string.startIndex, offsetBy: String.IndexDistance(2)))
    return string
}
```

Try this code instead

It converts the Int to a String first and checks if its 4 characters before adding the ":"